# Wordpress display image link in shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode that display an image when you use the image url inside it.

```
function image_code($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<img src="'.$content.'" class="user-imgs"/>';
}
add_shortcode('img', 'image_code');
```

So when I use the code like this:

```
[img]https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png[/img]
```

it display only the image like this:(in the css I have set the .user-imgs to max-width 600px)

```
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
```

But I want to display a link to the full image, like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png"><img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
```

How I can retrieve the image url used in shortcode and use it as a link in to the original image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse the `$content` parameter:

```
function image_code($atts, $content = null) {
    $url = esc_url( $content );
    return "<a href='$url'><img src='$url' class='user-imgs' /></a>";
}
```

Or pass the URL as parameter in case you want to use a different URL:

```
function image_code($atts, $content = null) {

    $args = shortcode_atts( array( 'url' => FALSE ), $atts  );
    $img  = esc_url( $content );
    $url  = $args['url'] ? esc_url( $args['url'] ) : $img;

    return "<a href='$url'><img src='$img' class='user-imgs' /></a>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
I used the first code, and it worked. Now it returns the correct url!